# ios Swift Chart issue

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I use Charts iOS library(https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and I have this code :

```
import UIKit
import Charts


    class ChartsViewController: UIViewController , ChartViewDelegate{

        var lineChartView: LineChartView?
        let months = ["Jan" , "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        let dollars1 = [1453.0,2352,5431,1442,5451,6486,1173,5678,9234,1345,9411,2212]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.lineChartView = LineChartView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 70, 300, 300))
            self.lineChartView!.delegate = self
            self.lineChartView!.descriptionText = "Tap node for details"
            self.lineChartView!.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
            self.lineChartView!.descriptionTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.lineChartView!.noDataText = "No data provided"
            setChartData(months)
            self.view.addSubview(self.lineChartView!)



        }
        func setChartData(months : [String]) {

            var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
            for var i = 0; i < months.count; i++ {
                yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(value: dollars1[i], xIndex: i))
            }

            let set1: LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals1, label: "First Set")
            set1.lineWidth = 10.0
            set1.circleRadius = 0.0 // the radius of the node circle
            set1.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
            set1.highlightColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
            set1.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
            var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()
            dataSets.append(set1)
            let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: months, dataSets: dataSets)
            data.setValueTextColor(UIColor.whiteColor())
            self.lineChartView!.data = data            
        }
```

and I get this :

https://postimg.org/image/6z6nk5nkn/

My problem is this :

I want to delete the grid on background(vertical and horizontal lines) but I dont be able because I dont find anything in the official library documentation.

Can you help me?

Comment: there is nobody that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.lineChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
self.lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to disable the grid :

```
lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
lineChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

Comment: with this method I disable only vertical lines , but for horizontal lines?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i forgot another properties, i updated my answer.